# find null value and empty string in nested data (Java)

Tags: java, json, null

I want to check if my data has null value.
The data in JSON format is below:

```
"{

    "totalAmount" : 20000,
    "items" : [
    {
        "id" : "9fd91eaf-2b9a-4bae-9692-4222f85e868",
        "name" : "X hotel",
        "itemType" : 0,
        "orderCount" : 2,
        "amount" : 5000
    },
    {
        "id" : "9fd91eaf-2b9a-4bae-9692-4222f85e869",
        "name": "Special Dinner",
        "itemType" : 1,
        "orderCount" : 1,
        "amount" : 10000
    }
    ]
}"
```

And here is my checker logic.

```
class NullCheck {
    public checkNull (Itinerary itinerary)
        Object nu = null;
    if (itinerary == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (itinerary.getTotalAmount() == null || itinerary.getItems() == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (itinerary.getItems().contains(null)) {
        return true;
    } else if (itinerary.getItems().stream().flatMap  // 
            (item -> Arrays.stream(item.getClass().getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(field -> { field.setAccessible(true); return field.get(nu) == null; } ) ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, IlligalAccessException is thrown at field.get(nu), and I can't figure out why my code doesn't work well.
As I read java document, It seems correct in syntax.
Can I ask which part of my code is failed?
further, some of the json format data is converted to object of type `String`, so I also need to check if the `string` is empty `string` or not.
Is there easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is 2 mistake in your code.

The first:

```
if (itinerary.getItems().stream().flatMap  // 
        (item -> Arrays.stream(item.getClass().getDeclaredFields()))
        .map(field -> { field.setAccessible(true); return field.get(nu) == null; } ) ) {
    return true;
}
```

the result of `.map` method is a `Stream<Boolean>`,not a bool expression.So there will be a syntax error and not be compiled.

The second:

```
return field.get(nu) == null;
```

this code will throw `NullPointerException` while the `filed` is an instance field.And the method `get` in `Field` can throw some `Exception`,so should try-catch on it.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for `Field.get`

> Returns the value of the field represented by this Field, on the
>   specified object. The value is automatically wrapped in an object if
>   it has a primitive type.

See, how it says on the specified object? That's because the Field object is no longer associated with a specific object.

Which means that `Field.get` operation need to be passed the `item` object, not the `null` assigned `nu` object you are currently passing.

This seems really tedious, do try to use a library like [this](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) for JSON schema validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object nu = null;
```

You are trying to get 'nu' which is a Null Object. That's the reason you are getting an IlligalAccessException.